# Assigning a static IP to a VMWare ubuntu instance?

Tags: ubuntu, ip

I run VMWare on my Mac laptop. What I'm trying to accomplish is that every time I start an Ubuntu virtual machine I created, the same static IP (e.g., 192.168.0.15) gets assigned to it by my Cisco router.

The router allows me to reserve an IP for a given mac address. But I tried both NAT and bridged networking and it didn't help. Furthermore I noticed that at times the assigned IP in the network changes while Ubuntu is running.

I assume the solution will come from assigning the mac address of the VM image to the right IP in the router, picking the right connection type for the VMWare image (which one?), and then do something within Ubuntu to ensure that the static IP is set.

I just don't know which actual commands are required.

Answer (score 1):

Use a bridged vNIC and reserve an IP for the vNIC's MAC address. You can find this using `ifconfig` from a terminal in Ubuntu. The MAC address is the HWaddr.

```
graeme@graeme:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:11:22:33:44:55  
          ...
          ...
          ...                                ^^^ there's the MAC address
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately that only worked temporarily. After some time the ip switched to a different one (e.g., from .15 to .18).